# QT Project File - Field Meanings

Tags: c++, qt

I'm interested in know what some of the fields in a standard QT application project file means ? Here is a example

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-04-02T11:06:19
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui xml

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = AV_Command
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    case.cpp \
    interview.cpp \
    parsexml.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    case.h \
    interview.h \
    parsexml.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

I understand what most of this is doing, except these 2 lines.

```
QT       += core gui xml

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QT += core gui xml` means that the build process should expect to find and include QtCore, QtGUI and QtXML libraries for your project. If you don't use any XML (and especially don't use the XML headers) you can remove `xml` from that list.

On the flip side... if you wanted to add Qt's SQL stuff, you'd need to add `sql` to the list otherwise you would get linker errors complaining about missing definitions.

The `greaterThan()` compares `QT_MAJOR_VERSION` against `4`. If true, then it adds `widgets` to the list of required QT libraries.

Answer (score 1):

```
QT       += core gui xml
```

Specifies what components of the Qt library you're using.
The second includes widgets depending on the version of Qt